# Run "bin/rails assets:precompile" in Dockerfile when building image fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to build my image for production but I'm facing a problem.

I run this command
`docker build -f docker/production/app/Dockerfile .`

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine3.12

# Install dependencies:
# - build-base: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
# - mysql-dev: Communicate with mysql through the mysql2 gem
# - libxslt-dev libxml2-dev: Nokogiri native dependencies
RUN apk --update --no-cache add build-base tzdata mysql-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev nodejs

RUN apk add --no-cache yarn --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community"

ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

COPY Gemfile* /var/www/app/
WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN bundle config set without 'development test'

RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY package.json package.json
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock

RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . /var/www/app/

EXPOSE 3000

# Clean up APK when done.
RUN rm -f /var/cache/apk/*

RUN bin/rails assets:precompile

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma/production.rb"]
```

The docker-compose is

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app:
    image: XYZ
    env_file:
      - docker/production/.env/redis
      - docker/production/.env/database
      - docker/production/.env/app
```

When running the command "bin/rails assets:precompile", I am having this issue

```
Step 17/19 : RUN bin/rails assets:precompile
 ---> Running in 57c98721e8c6
rails aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "REDIS_SERVER"
/var/www/app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:19:in `fetch'
/var/www/app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:19:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:85:in `configure_client'
/var/www/app/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:18:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/var/www/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command '/bin/sh -c bin/rails assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Docker could not access env variable. In my config/initializers/sidekiq.rb, I have

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_SERVER') }
end
```

And I configure my env variables in files like

```
docker/production/.env/redis
docker/production/.env/database
docker/production/.env/app
```

Is there a way to give docker access to these files?

Regards.

Comment: If that step needs to contact Redis, it can't run in a Dockerfile anyways; you'll have to move that setup to an entrypoint script.  The build step won't have access to the `env_file:` variables and won't be able to contact other Compose-based services.

Comment: So the compilation of the assets will happen during the start of the container?

Comment: Yes.  In the abstract that probably shouldn't depend on Redis/Sidekiq but if you're eagerly setting up a connection in an initializer it might be unavoidable.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze. I will try to remove these dependencies on initializing, but I still have the issue on the database env variables.

Comment: Actually I might move all my env variables into the rails credentials.